# text in UITableViewCell get remove when user scroll uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield, reuseidentifier

I am working on the project which have lots of forms(like sign up forms)approx 20-25forms are there and each forms have 8-9 input box i.e textfields.

1) I have created custom UITableViewCell
2) I cell for row at index i Wrote below code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(indexPath.row==0){
            NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
            customcell *cell = (DropdownCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customcell owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            cell.Txtlist.placeholder = @"Select type of meeting";
            self.txtType1 = cell.Txtlist;  // i had created the local variable uitextfield.So that i can access that locally in my application.
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell;
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1){
            NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = cell;
            customcell *cell = (customcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customcell owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            cell.Txtlist.placeholder = @"Select Client Name";
            self.txtType2 = cell.Txtlist;  // i had created the local variable uitextfield.So that i can access that locally in my application.
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell;
        }
}
```

3)UI is proper.
But problem is when i write some text in textfield in row = 0  and scroll the uitableview. value of textfield get remove.

How can i solve this.
Please help.
Also help me if there is better approach to implement forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding that you are using 4-5 textfield on single page then you have to store those values somewhere like in array or dictionary so that whenever cellForRowAtIndex will be called for that particular filled data cell then this cell will use that array or dictionary to show to previous filled data.
Or "in simply you have to store the values".

Answer (score 0):

You are not reusing the table view cells properly.
Read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) once.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Can you help me by pointing out the exact mistake.

Answer (score 0):

1. initialise a global NSMutableDictionary object.

   // in header
   NSMutableDictionary *values;
2. user <key,pair> value feature of dictionary.

   // in view-did-load method
   values = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

   // set your text value for given
   [values setValue:@"" forKey:@(0)]; // your row index 0
   [values setValue:@"" forKey:@(1)]; // index 1
3. Set TextField Delegate & tag, also set stored text.

   cell.Txtlist.delegate = self;
   cell.Txtlist.tag = indexPath.row;
   NSString *value = values[@(indexPath.row)];
   cell.Txtlist.text = value;
4. implement TextField methods,

   - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
     {
     [values setValue:textField.text forKey:@(textField.tag)];
     }

Enjoy... Keep up the good work.